# How to call a function of db table row class from a controller in zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I am trying to call a function exists in my dbtable row class ie Test.php.and I want to call it from my controller. My dbtable class is Tests.

```
$obj=new Model_Test();
$obj->testFunction();
```

but it's not working and giving the below error.

> Notice: Undefined variable: modelTest in /opt/lampp/htdocs/TestApp/application/modules/public/controllers/TestsController.php on line 19
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function testFunction() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/TestApp/application/modules/public/controllers/TestsController.php on line 19

I need to how can I call that function form my cotroller.

Comment: Please show us some more code (maybe just missing the NEW before the object)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have something like this on line #19

```
$modelTest->testFunction();
```

The problem is, `$modelTest` has not been defined.

You should probably have something like this prior to line #19

```
$modelTest = new Model_Test;
```